# Which is the "Action Phase"?

Tags: starcraft

A number of cards in the Starcraft Board Game (I believe it's exclusive to those from the Brood War expansion) refer to actions to be done during, or after, the "Action Phase".

The official instructions list only three phases; Planning, Execution, and Regrouping.

From context, I would guess that "Action Phase" is synonymous to "Execution Phase" (many of the cards seem overpowered otherwise), but I was hoping to find an official answer rather than conjecture: **Which phase is the "Action Phase?"**

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the Action Phase is unique to the Brood Wars Expansion. A quick search of the phrase "Action Phase" in the digital version of both rule books only turned up results in the Brood Wars version.

Like you, I found a lot of people saying that the Action Phase was synonymous with the Execution Phase (example [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/373598/recharge-once-per-action-phase)). The most convincing piece of evidence is straight from the Fantasy Flight Games forums. [This question](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_foros_discusion.asp?efid=6&efcid=28&efidt=305154) is answered by saying that the Action Phase is identical to the Execution Phase, but since it's on the game designer's website, I would imagine a moderator would have corrected it had it been wrong. It looks like questions are answered by people from FFG at least occasionally, so they are probably looking in on rules questions to make sure information was correct. Not the solid answer you were looking for, but I think it confirms the two are the same.